# Multi select in the calendar

Tags: java, swing, calendar

I need to add a calendar in which it will be possible to choose a day, when choosing a day, it is necessary that a field appear where you can specify a time interval, the time interval is 2 int, what time you came and what time you left, it doesn’t matter, for them I use combo box, I do not understand how to make this field appear after I select a day in the calendar. The second case is when you need to select several days at a time and one field should appear in which I will prescribe a time interval and this time will correspond to all selected days.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of copying code, I’m providing an [example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/java-swing-date-picker-example/) to walk you through the process with swing. It shows a thorough example of creating a calendar and providing selection capabilities to the end user.

Since no code was provided, I’m not sure if an attempt had been made to solve the question, so this would give insight and the answer which is more helpful than just lines of code.

Comment: I need something like https://gist.github.com/mmdemirbas/07f7cb0840d68ef00e75cd60e9b97ce1